# How to remove status bar on some ViewControllers in an ios app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that is showing the status bar on most screens. Most of the app is locked to portrait mode but one section makes sense to be in landscape. I would like to transition to the landscape with a modal slide in which works fine. The issue is I want the landscape view to hide the status bar. Currently is looks ugly as the status bar just switches to the top of the landscape view and shows a little black bar on the portrait one as it slides in. Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```